# Multivariable decisions

Tags: logic-programming

I am running into a situation where my program can have different outcomes depending on the state of some variables. 4 variables are involved and they can all have different ( 3 to 4 different states). All the possible combinations are leading me to about 48 different cases which would be resolved using a 4 level deep nested if/else structure. So, I have a couple of questions,

1. Is there a better technique to draw logic or decision tables or some other structure so that you can model a decision tree for this many outcomes? When a decision is dependent on only 2 variables you can easily model this on a spreadsheet which is two dimensional by its nature but how do you deal with a case like the one I mentioned?
2. Other than a 4 level deep nested if/else structure is there a better programming technique to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a '[decision table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table)'

[image: decision table example]

it's tedious to fill it out, but it forces you to consider all possibilities - and you may see patterns in the variable values and/or outputs that will let you write more compact if-logic

Comment: Just to extend, [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) are a more complex variation on decision tables but can help you define the minimal logical evaluations necessary to achieve the branching logic.

Comment: @Flater thanks for the reference though Karnaugh maps only work with boolean variables

Comment: Any value can be broken down into binary values (OP has 3-4 values per variable, which can be expressed using 2 bits), but I do agree that for a large range of values it becomes increasingly complex.